# Laravel csrf_field() - only for forms with method="POST"?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, csrf

I know nothing about CSRF attacks, but I know that in Laravel we are supposed to include a hidden CSRF token field in the form:

```
<form method="POST" action="/profile">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    ...
</form>
```

Should we use include it in the forms with method="GET"?

```
<form method="GET" action="/search">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    ...
</form>
```

For example, I have a search input (form) with the method="GET" - so everything will be visible in the URL, including CSRF token... and that's not problem for me at all, but I'm just unsure does it make sense to have it in the "GET" forms?

Comment: you dont need csrf token for get requests

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Security against CSRF attacks via GET requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45229789/security-against-csrf-attacks-via-get-requests)

Comment: See also [why no csrf for GET requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45555614/why-no-csrf-for-get-requests)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you don't need to add CSRF token with Form Get Request. Cross-site request forgeries(CSRF) are a type of malicious exploit whereby unauthorized commands are performed on behalf of an authenticated user.

You can basic details over [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf)

Answer (score 0):

Actually CSRF is possible in both GET as well as POST.

example:

```html
<img src="https://somesite.com/adduser.php?username=test&password=test&role=admin">
```

If you have a Insecure function that uses GET then you will also be able to forge a request to it by simply putting it in a image.

This is why in addition to CSRF Tokens in the request itself its often considered to be implemented in cookies or even headers in combinition with:

- Origin Security Checks
- SameSite attribute on the session cookie set to 'Strict'