# why no csrf for GET requests

Tags: csrf, csrf-protection

I have read that there is no need for CSRF on GET requests since they are considered safe.

However one scenario I can think of is an attack like this:

```
<img src="https://otherdomain.com/logout" />
```

This would be bad without CSRF. Of course, one could require the logout route to require post, but I often see it implemented as a simple href.

Furthermore, why are GETs safe at all? They still leak the data in the response...

Comment: That's why the HTTP spec discourages changing state with GET requests

Comment: This is also why you don't log out on a GET request; what if your browser [pre-fetches it?](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/296281730984316928)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a write-only attack.  From the [OWASP page on CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)):

> CSRF attacks target functionality that causes a state change on the server, such as changing the victim's email address or password, or purchasing something. ***Forcing the victim to retrieve data doesn't benefit an attacker because the attacker doesn't receive the response***, the victim does. As such, CSRF attacks target state-changing requests.

As long as GET requests don't change state, they are of no value to the hacker.

I suppose the logout example you provided could pose an inconvenience to a user, but there is no actual harm and no actual benefit to the hacker.

Comment: Good point. But this only holds true if a proper CORS policy is in place. Otherwise retrieving/stealing data would be possible.

Comment: If CORS isn't set up, the browser falls back to the [same origin policy](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8264/why-is-the-same-origin-policy-so-important) which will block any AJAX request. Any non-AJAX request, of course, is displayed to the end user, not the hacker, so even if data are retrieved, they can't be read by the hacker.

Comment: I don't understand what could prevent a script to GET sensitive data of the logged in user (for example profile info) and then POST it back to the malicious domain.

Comment: @kwentine You're right, but that would require a different type of attack known as [XSS](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/138987/difference-between-xss-and-csrf). If you can get a script to do that, you can also get a script to walk the DOM and read the CSRF token, making the mitigation useless. So you have to guard against XSS if you're going to guard against CSRF.

Comment: @JohnWu I see your point. I actually had a misunderstanding of CORS that wouldn't let an attacker access the response content of a GET request issued from his domain (and hence not POST it back) unless explicitly allowed by the target domain (with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header for example)